# QGIS - add Layer From URL (GetCapabilities)

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, url, getcapabilities

I'm trying to add a layer to my QGIS project from this URL: http://quegis.labcd.unipi.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Using a WMS connection, I'm able to open it in jpeg or PNG format, but I don't know how to retrieve the alphanumeric part, i.e. feature attributes, which is the interesting part for me. Am I making a mistake or is it impossible via WMS?

Comment: which alphanumeric part? it is just a map of buildings when I view it

Comment: So it's not my problem. I can't see anything else because there is nothing else, right?

Comment: What makes you think there should be an alphanumeric part? Are you expecting an attribute table? A WFS (web *feature* service) layer could have an attribute table, but a WMS (web *map* service) layer doesn't have attributes because it's just a raster image.

Comment: I need an attribute table, but I'm not sure that there is one. Is there a way to verify if the alphanumeric part exists?

Comment: WMS only provides image tiles.  There is no 'alphanumeric part' or attribute table.  It does not exist when working with a WMS.  You need a WFS

Comment: Thank you all. I understand it, but can I use WFS, exploiting that URL in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get attribute information from a WMS by using a GetFeatureInfo request.  A GetFeatureInfo request is a request for information at a point location (a pixel location in the map image).

GetFeatureInfo is an optional operation of a WMS, you can tell whether a layer supports such a query by looking at the GetCapabilities response, in your example it is (queryable="1"):

```
<Layer queryable="1">
    <Name>benigeo</Name>
    <Title>benigeo</Title>
```

In QGIS the GetFeatureInfo request is performed using the 'Identify Features` tool.

In this case there is also an associated WFS:

```
http://quegis.labcd.unipi.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

And you could fetch data using a GetFeature request

Comment: By the way, it's actually pretty frequent that a published WMS service is shadowed by a WFS which may or may not be publicized. Ditto ArcGisMapServer -> ArcGisFeatureServer. It's always worth just making the obvious URL changes and seeing if it can be coaxed into working. Not always, of course.

Comment: +/- or a WCS, depending on the input data